# Xpath for retrieving all the tags inside parent

Tags: xpath

Find a particular tag inside parent tag using xpath:

Sample input:

```
<Table>
    <Tbody>
        <Row> 
            <cell><para> <ref> </ref> <ref> </ref> </para>  </cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <cell><para>  <a1> </a1><ref> </ref> </para>  </cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <cell><para>  <ref> </ref></para>  </cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <cell><para>  <b1> </b1></para>  </cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <cell><para>  <b1> </b1> <c1> </c1></para>  </cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <cell><para>  <ref> </ref> <c1> </c1></para>  </cell>
        </Row>
    <Thead>
```

Expected output:

- cell1-para it should return 0
- cell2-para it should return 1
- cell3-para it should return 0
- cell4-para it should return 1
- cell5-para it should return 2
- cell6-para it should return 1

How to find out the count of non ref tag inside cell?

There maybe multiple tags inside a para. Name may be anything. But we need to check only ref alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is not capable of returning results for every `para` element - that's something you should do in the higher-level language XPath is embedded into (for example, XSLT, XQuery, Java, PHP, Python, Perl...).

To retrieve a single result, for an input like

```
<cell><para> <ref> </ref> <ref> </ref> </para>  </cell>
```

use the following XPath expression

```
count(//para/*[not(self::ref)])
```

which, in this case, will yield

```
0
```

---

**EDIT**: This is only true for XPath 1.0, as Sean B. Durkin has pointed out. It is possible in Xpath 2.0 and 3.0, where XPath functions can be axis steps and where sequences are always evaluated entirely. See [Sean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684821/1987598) for an XPath 2.0 solution.

Comment: You should qualify your statement 'XPath is not capable of …'.  Version 2.0 can do it rather easily.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Yes, you are right of course. I'll edit the answer in a second.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XPath 2.0 or 3.0, and the focus node is the parent of Table, then the following expression...

```
Table/Tbody/Row/cell/para/count(decendant::ref)
```

... when applied to the given sample input document will evaluate to this sequence of xs:integer...

```
(0,1,0,1,2,1)
```

---

Just for fun, here is an equivalent alternative expression ...

```
for $p in Table/Tbody/Row/cell return count($p//ref)
```